# What are other options to deploy images in SharePoint via VS?

Tags: solution-deployment

Option 1.  Add mapped folder and add files to it.

Option 2.  Add module folder and modify the elements.xml file to deploy this image to the required library.

Option 3.  Can it be done via an empty element?

Option 4.  Can it be done by adding the image to the package explorer by right-click -> add? (the same way we deploy dlls?)

Option 5.  Any other option?